# Animation not working if has async function before

Tags: flutter

My animation doesn't start at all and the screen is white for the whole 4 seconds of the timeout function called `waitForAnimationComplete()`

The funniest part is that with hot reload everything works perfectly but on first start nothing, white screen.

Unfortunately release app has no hot reload so I can't ignore this problem

The idea in this view is to start with a white screen and then (after calculating the colors) change slowly to the colored view with an animation from white to color

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_project/home/home.dart';
import 'package:my_project/stile/theme_colors.dart';

class LoadingHome extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoadingHomeState createState() => _LoadingHomeState();
}

class _LoadingHomeState extends State<LoadingHome> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController controller;
  Animation<Color> background;

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    controller = AnimationController(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 2000), vsync: this);

    openHome();
  }

  openHome() async{
    double hue = await recoverColor();
    startTransition(hue);

    await Future.wait([waitForAnimationComplete()]);
    Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => Home())
    );
  }

  Future<double> recoverColor() async {
    return 0.6;
  }

  startTransition(double hue) {
    if(hue == null)
      ThemeColors.initColors();
    else
      ThemeColors.initColors(hue: hue);

    background = ColorTween(
      begin: Colors.white,
      end: ThemeColors.dark,
    ).animate(controller);
    controller.forward(); // starts animation
  }

  Future<void> waitForAnimationComplete() async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 4));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return controller.isAnimating ? AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: background,
      builder: (BuildContext context, child) => BodyLoadHome(
        background: background.value,
      ),
    ) : BodyLoadHome(
      background: Colors.white,
    );
  }
}

class BodyLoadHome extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color background;

  BodyLoadHome({this.background});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: background,
    );
  }
}
```

This is the first view of my app so I have to call `ThemeColors.initColors()` before using my awesome `ThemeColors` . `ThemeColors.initColors()` is a function that calculates all my `ThemeColors` starting from the `hue` coming from internal memory, so I need to call `recoverColor()` then `ThemeColors.initColors()` and then start the animation using the `ThemeColors`

I know the problem is the Future `recoverColor()` because everything works if I change it to a normal function, here are my changes:

```
openHome() async{
  double hue = recoverColor(); <--------------
  startTransition(hue);

  await Future.wait([waitForAnimationComplete()]);
  Navigator.pushReplacement(
      context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => Home())
  );
}

double recoverColor() { <--------------
  return 0.6;
}
```

With this changes everything works. Obviously the real `recoverColor()` isn't that simple, in this function i should read the hue from internal storage so `recoverColor()` must be a Future.

How can I make it work even with the Future `recoverColor()`?

EDIT:

The suggestion to use `.addListener()` with `setState()` works but i think I found a more efficent but similar solution:

Change:

```
controller.forward(); // starts animation
```

To:

```
setState(() {
      controller.forward(); // starts animation
    });
```

So that we call `setState()` only once to change from `BodyLoadHome` to `AnimatedBuilder`. I think that when `AnimatedBuilder` is in use he calls `setState()` when needed

Comment: you have to call `setState` after calling `forward()` so that your widget builds `AnimatedBuilder` and not `BodyLoadHome`, also check what `controller.forward()` returns and use it for delayed calling `Navigator.pushReplacement`

Comment: but honestly i would always return `AnimatedBuilder` in order to make the code simple, or even better `AnimatedContainer` with 2 different `color:` values

Comment: Well thanks but I prefer to see the loading screen for a minimum of 4 secs.

Comment: I don't think is so easy to use always `AnimatedBuilder` because takes `background` in the constructor and `background` is null at the beginning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to call `setState` when you animation position changes. Therefore you never see the change in the UI. Add a listener to your `AnimationController` that calls `setState` when you create the controller in `initState`.

```dart
controller.addListener(() {
  setState(() {});
});
```

You can read [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/tutorial) official flutter tutorial to learn the basics of animations in flutter.

Comment: you dont need `addListener` and calling `setState` in every animation frame - the animation is handled by `AnimatedBuilder` - the real issue is that is is not build since the previous `build()` method returned `BodyLoadHome` as `controller.isAnimating` was `false` - thats why i said to always return `AnimatedBuilder`